# Django Filter with AND

Tags: python, django

Am having a django query to filter trough a model and print out the condition that meets the search.

Here is the views

```
if user_search != '' and (start_date != '' and end_date != ''):
    items = Order.objects.filter(
         Q(client__email__iexact=user_search) , Q(created_on__range=(start_date, end_date))
        )
    print "items ", items
```

The django filter is to print email address the user searched for, that falls within the date range.
But the code am having also prints email that wasn't searched for but falls within the date range

Here is the model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    client               =      models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "order_user")
    order_number         =      models.CharField(max_length = 12)null=True)
    terms_and_conditions =      models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order_status         =      models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = ORDER_STATUS, default = "new")
    created_on           =      models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    edited_on            =      models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.order_number
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that in Django 1.8. Having two `Q` args should be equivalent to using the `&` operator i.e. `Q(client__email__iexact=user_search) & Q(created_on__range=(start_date, end_date)`. Note you don't really need `Q` here at all. Your code could be simplified to `Order.objects.filter(client__email__iexact=user_search, created_on__range=(start_date, end_date))`.

Comment: @Alasdair Used & operator but still prints email address i didn't search for

Comment: My point is that your existing code **shouldn't** return email addresses if the date is outside the range. It might help if you show some more code that can reproduce the problem, and the results that you are getting. Maybe you aren't running the code you think you are (e.g. you haven't restarted the server after changing code).

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` for doing AND operations on `Q` objects.

```
if user_search != '' and (start_date != '' and end_date != ''):
    items = Order.objects.filter(
         Q(client__email__iexact=user_search) & Q(created_on__range=(start_date, end_date))
        )
    print "items ", items
```

Comment: Used & operator but still prints email address i didn't search for

Comment: note that we used `iexact` which should do a case-insensitive match. POst ur `Order` model's code.

Comment: am using django inbuilt User model